# Regex for pattern that starts with ABC, then B's and/or C's, and ends with CBA

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string that can contain only A's, B's and C's.

I have substrings of a certain pattern that I want to extract: they start with ABC, continue with a combination of B's and C's, and end with CBA.

The naive solution is to use `ABC[BC]*CBA`.

However, that will not cover the `ABCBA` string. Is there a "pythonic" way to address this, other than using `|` to look for two possible RE's?

Comment: Matt, you do not need to use lookarounds here, your regex is fine, the only fix to be done is to enclose the `C[BC]*` part with an optional group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much for your solution! Are optional groups more preferable than lookaround?

Comment: You may compare the steps: [34 (mine)](https://regex101.com/r/50I7oM/3) vs. [42 (Biffen's)](https://regex101.com/r/6UNzCc/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use lookarounds, use an optional group:

```
ABC(?:[BC]*C)?BA
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/50I7oM/3).

**Details**

- `ABC` - an `ABC` substring
- `(?:[BC]*C)?` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) matching 0 or more occurrences of `B` or `C` chars followed with a `C` letter
- `BA` - a `BA` substring.

This will effectively match `AB` that can only be followed with `C` and then any number of `B` or `C` letters (but this steak of chars is optional) followed with `CBA`.

Note that depending on what you are doing with the pattern, a capturing group will also do, `ABC([BC]*C)?BA`.

Comment: or also `ABC(?:[BC]*C)?BA`, maybe a bit more efficient

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Yes, in general, the more rightmost an optional thing is, the more efficient it turns out.

Comment: because it can't backtrack before first C

Answer (score 5):

You can use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

[`AB(?=C)[BC]*(?<=C)BA`](https://regex101.com/r/6UNzCc/1)

I.e. make sure `AB` is followed by `C` and `BA` is preceded by `C`, even if they are the same `C`.

Comment: can be simplified with just one lookaround (the lookahead for example), because one `C` has to be consumed

Comment: this is using extended features to RE. confirmed, does work.

Comment: @anubhava True.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this answer (with @anubhava 's suggestion).

Comment: @Biffen indeed i was thinking to this solution

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul There is a much simpler solution without lookarounds. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582770/3832970)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, indeed, the advantage of yours is that it's more efficient, i didn't think of it first because it's like a `|` except one branch is empty however don't understand what op meant by "pythonic"

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I think people (mis|over)use the word "pythonic". As far as regex is concerned, "pythonic" might mean "using the most commonly used Python `re` regex features".